# Video JS not playing properly in iOS safari browser and Android Default Browser

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

Videos Play normally on Desktop Version in all browser.

But in **iOS** video is not playing exceeding time of 22 min.

Error message
`The Media playback was aborted due to a  corruption problem ....`

In Android **Kitkat** and **lollipop** or less version, Videos doesn't play at all.
`The Media could not be loaded, either because the server or network ....`

Below is the Code in applied for WordPress

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginUser[$ID]" class="videoArchive__link videoB_link" id="#loginUser-[$ID]; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $imgThumb; ?>" alt="Thumbnail">
</a>
```

```
jQuery(".videoB_link").on("click", function() {
    var modalBox = jQuery(this).attr("data-target");
    var videoID = jQuery(modalBox + " .video-js").attr("id");

    playerID = document.getElementById('my_video_[$ID]; ?>');

        var player = videojs(videoID, {
        html5: {
            nativeAudioTracks: false,
            nativeVideoTracks: false,
            hls: {
              overrideNative: true
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){ player.play(); }, 1000);
    if(player) player.hlsQualitySelector();
    playerID.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);

    jQuery("#close[$ID]").on("click", function() {
        player.pause();
    });

    jQuery('.modal').on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target !== this)
            return;

        player.pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: Did it actually say _corruption_, or connection problem? Either way, this sounds more like a server-side issue, with how exactly the videos are delivered.

Comment: There are currently 5 videos which 4 videos are below 21 min and working well!

Comment: It also seems to me as as server-side problem as i added other CDN videos which works fine.
Video are delivered directly from the web server as of website is hosted on(shared Hosting). @CBroe